# CAD modeller with support for interactive events

Tags: python, cad

I am new to CAD. However, I am interested in implementing some interactive geometric algorithms in 3d using CAD software. There seem to be many good open-source options available online e.g. OpenJSCAD, Implicit, FreeCAD.

However, from the little I CAD I know, we program a 3d model in a scripting language of the CAD package. Then we get an STL file which is visualized **offline** using standard visualizing software.

I would like to have a Python / Haskell based CAD modeller, which has support for event-handling, say through call-back functions.

Matplotlib of Python for instance, in Python has wonderful [support](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) for precisely this purpose. But from what I know it works only for 2d.

A typical usage scenario would be the user initiates a random point-cloud in 3d. The point cloud is rendered to the screen. By then pressing the key 'C', we can see each step of the construction of a convex hull algorithm.

As the algorithm construction proceeds, we can spin it around, zoom in on interesting parts etc.

Do such packages exist? Ideally, in Python or Haskell.

Comment: Matplotlib is not limited to 2D (any more at least) https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/index.html

Comment: Also there is Mayavi: http://code.enthought.com/pages/mayavi-project.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [pythonOCC](http://www.pythonocc.org), it is built on an open source real geometric kernel (opencascade).

You will have to explore and see if it answers your use case, but I think you can achieve a lot with it. 
See also 'Related projects' on the site, there might be something else which might interest you.

Answer (score -1):

Not using CAD software but using python is Jupyter [VPython](http://vpython.org/).

Assuming that you already have a recent Python version of python installed you can install VPython with:

```
pip install vpython --upgrade
```

This will let you start Jupyter VPython kernels by running:

```
jupyter notebook
```

and on the resulting webpage, http://localhost:8888 by default, selecting new VPython on the top right.

- Free Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- You can do almost exactly the sort of thing you are looking for
- not a CAD program

I also recommend checking out the source and the demos from [github](https://github.com/BruceSherwood/vpython-jupyter), one of said demos:
[image]